# What is the best way to save XML string(without compression) in MariaDB table using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, mariadb

I am hitting a rest api with xml body and I want to log that xml in the database. I am using MariaDB. What is the best way to save XML string(without compression) in MariaDB table using Python?

Comment: Is the XML part really relevant to the question?

Comment: Why not? Some of the other database have xml as column type.